# Is there a way to fetch without entering the server address

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, fetch-api

This might be a really dumb question, but is there a way to fetch without entering the server address? I'm wondering if I can just use "/init" instead of "http://localhost:3000/init"

```
try{
    const result = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/init",
    {
      method:"GET",
      headers:{
        "content-type":"application/json"
      }
    });
    response = await result.json();
    }
  catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to fetch without entering the server address

No.

In node.js, `node-fetch` requires a fully qualified URL.  There is no "default" target domain or path that it could substitute like there is inside a browser web page with the browser version of `fetch()`.

From the node-fetch [documentation](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#fetchurl-options):

```
fetch(url[, options])

url should be an absolute url, such as https://example.com/. 
A path-relative URL (/file/under/root) or protocol-relative URL 
(//can-be-http-or-https.com/) will result in a rejected Promise.
```

If the problem you're really trying to solve here is to be able to write code that will work with different hosts (run locally and in a hosting environment), then you can set some sort of configuration variable with the hostname and then construct your URL using the host name in the configuration variable.